# How can I get Custom Elements / Web Component names to be suggested by VS Code's Emmett / IntelliSense?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, web-component, custom-element, emmet

I've added a .html-custom-data.json file that's referenced correctly in the vscode -> settings.json, as hovering over a custom web component in HTML will display the description, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> after the opening tag will include a list of possible attributes.

What I haven't figured out is how to get the Emmett / IntelliSense to suggest any of my web component names so you can hit tab and have them added.

What do I need to do to get a `<my-element>` as a suggestion when I start typing "my- " in an HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet. See

- [The documentation of current limitations of custom data](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/blob/main/samples/webcomponents/README.md#limitations)
- Issue ticket for the fix for the [Emmet support for custom HTML tags / attributes #64032](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64032)

I'd try to say more, but there's really nothing more to say at the moment. The linked issue ticket has been in the backlog since 2018 and been passed around to three different assignees. If you have time to spare and want to learn some things you could try to contribute a pull request. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks! That would be interesting to learn how to contribute, I'll have to look at that.

My current workaround, is adding each of my custom web components as an Emmet snippet manually.